# How to Post JSON array using Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I need to post an JSON object using Retrofit 2. My JSON object is

> {
>                   "logTime" : "",
>                   "datas" : [
>                         {
>                           "dat1": "1",
>                           " dat2": "", 
>                           " dat3": "",
>                           " dat4": "",
>                           " dat5": ""
>                         },
>                         {
>                           "dat1": "1",
>                           " dat2": "", 
>                           " dat3": "",
>                           " dat4": "",
>                           " dat5": ""
>                         }
>   ]}

I have tried using following code:

API Services

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIU"
})
@POST("/api/employee/checkin")
Call<String> CHECKIN(@Body String data);
```

Activity Class

```
JSONStringer jsonStringer = null;
    try {
        jsonStringer=new JSONStringer().object().key("logTime").value("")
                .key("datas")
                .array()
                .object().key("dat1").value("1")
                .key("dat2").value("3")
                .key("dat3").value("5")
                .key("dat4").value("5")
                .endObject()
                .endArray()
                .endObject();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ApiService service = retroClient.getApiService();

    Call<String> login = service.CHECKIN(String.valueOf(jsonStringer));

    login.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            try {
                String val = response.body();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

I got "Error: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)" while using this code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Which line?

Comment: Remove header and try again

Comment: @KNeerajLal
Error occurs in ApiService.CHECKIN

Comment: @RajeshKoshti Same error occurs

Comment: How to pass the below JSON object using Field map?

{ "logTime" : "", "datas" : [ { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
}, { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
} ]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

Api Services

```
 @POST("/api/employee/checkin")
Call<Sample> CHECKIN(@Body JSONStringer data);
```

API Client

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("x-access-token", "eyJhbGci");

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();



    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Activity

```
 ApiService service = retroClient.getApiService();

    Call<Sample> call = service.CHECKIN(jsonStringer);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Sample>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Sample> call, Response<Sample> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Sample result = response.body();


            } else {
                // response received but request not successful (like 400,401,403 etc)
                //Handle errors
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Sample> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rajesh Kanna

Answer (score 3):

**use GSON lib**

add this dependency in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

**API Services**

```
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIU"
})
@POST("/api/employee/checkin")
Call<String> CHECKIN(@Body String data);
```

**Activity Class**

```
try {

            JsonArray datas = new JsonArray();

            JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
            object.addProperty("dat1","1");
            object.addProperty("dat2", "");
            object.addProperty("dat3", "");
            object.addProperty("dat4", "");
            object.addProperty("dat5", "");

            datas.add(object);

            JsonObject req = new JsonObject();
            req.addProperty("logTime", "");
            req.addProperty("datas", new Gson().toJson(datas));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    ApiService service = retroClient.getApiService();

    Call<String> login = service.CHECKIN(String.valueOf(req));

    login.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            try {
                String val = response.body();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This error occurs

@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)
                      for method ApiService.CHECKIN

Comment: Receiving Bad Request when removing @FormUrlEncoded

Comment: How to pass the below JSON object using Field map?

{ "logTime" : "", "datas" : [ { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
}, { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
} ]}

Answer (score 0):

When using the `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation, pass parameters using the `@Field` param instead of `@Body`. Hence do this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIU"
})
@POST("/api/employee/checkin")
Call<String> CHECKIN(@Field("data") String data);
```

I have assumed your server expects a `data` key which will have the details. If it is something else, please change it in here `@Field("data")`

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIU"
})
@POST("/api/employee/checkin")
Call<String> CHECKIN(@Field("logTime") String logTime, @Field("datas") String datas);
```

Comment: Received this error 
@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)

Comment: How? The code I have provided only has `@Field` parameter. Secondly, the annotation also mentioned is also `@FormUrlEncoded` and not `@Multipart`. Are you sure you have the exact same code in your app?

Comment: I got this response when using @Field

Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://test.xxxx.yyy/api/employee/checkin}

Request{method=POST, url=http://test.xxxx.yyy/api/employee/checkin, tag=null}

Comment: This means your API does not expect data as `@FormUrlEncoded`. Ask the backend team, where would they be looking for data. If they are looking for it in the `@Body` then you should create your own custom object and add GSON serializer to your Retrofit object.

Comment: How to pass the below JSON object using Field map?

{ "logTime" : "", "datas" : [ { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
}, { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
} ]}

Comment: Is your backend team only expecting 2 variables, that is; `logTime` and `datas`?

Comment: Yes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I got invalid request error.  If I give the datas array as empty it works. Otherwise it shows invalid request error.

Answer (score -3):

Have you added RetroFit to build.gradle ?

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

Comment: Yes I have added.

Comment: How to pass the below JSON object using Field map?

{ "logTime" : "", "datas" : [ { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
}, { "dat1": "1", " dat2": "", " dat3": "", " dat4": "", " dat5": ""
} ]}